# extract an array from list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a list such:

```
List<string> list =Arrays.asList("2014-06-20 [txt1:executed]","2014-06-21 [txt2:in progressed]");
```

I want to extract the contents to an array:

```
arr[0] =2014-06-20
arr[1] =executed
arr[2] =2014-06-21
arr[3] =in progressed
```

Comment: Please properly format so we can understand how the data in the list looks like. It is unclear

Comment: Hi Gilad Green, the quesion reformated.

Comment: ? That's not valid Java

Comment: @userY - yap - I formatted it. But what I meant is that you please post compiling java code of the list initialized with the strings. It is not clear how it is actually formatted

Comment: Do you think the declaration statement for the list is correct?

Comment: Please post a code that compiles.

Comment: And what have you tried so far to get to that goal?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: I post the code again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at **regular expressions**. They are quite powerfull to split Strings according to your wishes.
Here is an example how you can split your String.

```
    String regex = "([0-9-]+)\\s+\\[\\w*:([\\w\\s]*)]";
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("2014-06-20 [txt1:executed]","2014-06-21 [txt2:in progressed]");
    String date = list.get(0).replaceAll(regex, "$1");
    String status = list.get(0).replaceAll(regex, "$2");
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Alext I modified my question!

Comment: This will return the all text **2014-06-20 [txt1:executed]** but I want to split **2014-06-20** to **arr[0]** and **executed** to **arr[1]** and the second element such that.

Comment: Hi @userY, I have changed my answer. I hope this answer suits you.

Comment: Hi thanks @Alex, this prefect solution to my problem.

Comment: Hi @userY, you are welcome. I have just seen a small bug in the regex expression. I improved the code again. This works now.

Comment: Excellent help @Alex, now element 2 of the array list is splited thanks.